# How to determine count points in x axis in Chars C#

Tags: c#, charts

I use charts in c# and there problem in this image:
[image: charts]

I want to reduce the count this dates in x axis. How? I try this code:

```
chart1.Series["Bill"].Points.AddXY(all[0].tblBill_Date, all[0].tblBill_Amount);
chart1.Series["Bill"].Points.AddXY(all[1].tblBill_Date, all[1].tblBill_Amount);
chart1.Series["Bill"].Points.AddXY(all[all.Count - 1].tblBill_Date, all[all.Count - 1].tblBill_Amount);
```

Comment: Enlarge the interval on the axis to 2 days?